# Sum range by month in Google Sheets with date conditional

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with these columns:

- A (Date): Range of dates for the year
- B (Amount): An amount for an expense
- D (Month): Name of each month in the year (e.g. June, July, etc)

I've tried this as suggested to work in other posts:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B, ISDATE(A:A)*MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(D3&1))
```

I get the error `Function MONTH parameter 1 expects number values. But 'Date' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.` with this.

If I remove the header, I just get a `0` for the sum for each month, which is incorrect.

How do I get this to work for each month the way my sheet is setup?

What the sheet currently looks like:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_8DQTa9aXGjvd7twL6RZMcFyqxa4Sg7eVTcD2wDXH2A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Added link to a sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.  Not sure where you got that other formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,TEXT(A:A,"mmmm")=D3)
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(MONTH(D3:D10&1),
 QUERY(A2:B, "select month(A)+1,sum(B) group by month(A)"), 2, )))
```

[image]